# Call Method of Collection In Java

Tags: java, rcp

Here is the question.
I have a class which has a collection of a subclass type.

```
public class classOne{
    private Collection<classTwo> ...;
}
```

Now I want to store a value from second element as object

```
private ComboBoxViewerCellEditor cellEditor =  ComboBoxViewerCellEditor((Composite) getViewer().getControl(),SWT.READ_ONLY);
classOne one = (classOne) element;
Collection<classTwo> contactList = one.getClassTwo();
celleditor.setInput(contactList.getName());
```

Something like this but the last line of code is incorrect as that does not work.

So to sum up how can I get a getter from all instances of second class stored as a list of objects

Comment: in your class one, just introduce getter method like public Collection<classTwo> getAllClassTwo() { return classTwoList;} and in yout caller class just it like one.getAllClassTwo();

Comment: I have that and that returns a collection of object.But I need a value from each object in the list.

Comment: so instead of returning Collection as is, return new ArrayList<classTwo>(classTwoList); or better define type of your Collection as List rather than Collection or on client side convert it to list using above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (ClassTwo c2 : contactList) {
    names.add(c2.getName());
}
```

or, in Java 8:

```
List<String> names = contactList.stream()
                                .map(ClassTwo::getName)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```